# Get value of object from string

Tags: javascript

I've got this object:

```
var mallData = {
    StLouis: {
        Region: "CentralRegion",
        Mall: "BaybrookMall"
    },
    Woodlands: {
        Region: "CentralRegion",
        Mall: "WoodlandsMall"
    }
}
```

And to simplify, this variable:

```
var legalMallName = "StLouis";
```

And I want to be able to get,

```
console.log(mallData.legalMallName.Region);
```

But obvioulsy that doesn't work, I just don't know what to do instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just write : `mallData[legalMallName].Region`

Doing this you are accessing the property named after the value of `legalMallName` of the object `mallData` and then getting its property Region.

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable as a key:

```
var region = mallData[legalMallName].Region
```